# Cannot create custom style with React and Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm using `react-bootstrap` NPM package to make my `React` components look properly. I need to customize some of them, so I'm following the [official React-Bootstrap documentation](http://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#custom-styles), but the code throws the error `index.jsx:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addStyle' of undefined`.

This is my custom `Button` component code:

```
import React from "react";
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Button';
import bootstrapUtils from 'react-bootstrap/lib/utils/bootstrapUtils';

bootstrapUtils.addStyle(Button, 'custom');

export default class MediaItemButton extends React.Component {
    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                <style type="text/css">{`
                .btn-custom {
                    background-color: purple;
                    color: white;
                }
                `}</style>
                <Button bsStyle="primary">Custom</Button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: your bootstrapUtils object is not there, make sure your have the correct path to the react-bootstrap package, are you packaging this with webpack or something ? if so you need to do extra steps to make it available in your components class declarations

Comment: I've checked the path, and bootstrapUtils file is there. It also has addStyle function in exports. Also, I'm using Webpack.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change to this:

```
import { bootstrapUtils } from 'react-bootstrap/lib/utils';
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this as well:

```
    import React from "react";
    import Button from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Button';
    import bootstrapUtils from 'react-bootstrap/lib/utils/bootstrapUtils';

    bootstrapUtils.addStyle(Button, 'custom');

    export default class MediaItemButton extends React.Component {
        render() {
            var styles={
                "backgroundColor" : "purple",
                "color"           : "white"
            };
            return (
                <div>
                    <Button style={styles} bsStyle="primary">Custom</Button>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can I store my styles in .css, or I have to declare them in JS?

Comment: How the code above can be refactored to store styles in .css file?

Answer (score 0):

`bootstrapUtils` is a named export and not a default therefore you need to use `{}` around it.

Try using:
`import { bootstrapUtils } from 'react-bootstrap/lib/utils/bootstrapUtils';`

Comment: Geraint was almost right. You have to remove the "/bootstrapUtils" from the path.  See my answer